# Can anyone figure out why my loop is not working properly

Tags: c, if-statement, for-loop, logic

Here's my problem: I need a loop that goes through a char array and calculates how many people had the same grade, the amount of stars for each grade (one for each student with the same mark) and a percentage (please ignore it for this question):

```
void displayReport(char grade[][MAX_LETTER_SIZE]) {


                            for (i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
                if (grade[i] == "A+") {
                    A++;
                    strcat(star[0], sstar);
                    percentage[i] = percentage[i] + bperecentage;
                    break;
                }
                ..
```

Comment: `(1/12)*100` is equals to zero. Shouldn't it be `(1.0f/12.0f)*100.0f`?

Comment: You cannot compare C strings like `grade[i] == "A+"`. Use `strcmp()`.

Comment: `float roundf(float percentage[i]);` is a function prototype declaration and won't do anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Comparing strings is done with `strcmp`. Your current method just compares addresses.
2. `break` literally *breaks* out of the loop. I think you want `continue` here, which jumps to the top of the loop, performing the operations specified in the loop's head.
   **Actually**, you do not need any of these statements at all since if one clause of an `if...else if...else` structure evaluates to true the other ones aren't considered anymore at all.
3. `percentage` is uninitialized, so

   ```
   percentage[i] = percentage[i] + bperecentage;
   ```

   is undefined behavior.
4. `strcat` modified the buffer pointed to by its first argument. Since these are (empty) string literals in your case and string literals may not be written to, it's undefined behavior. If they were writable, you would need to allocate more memory anyway because `typeof("") == char[1]`.
5. `bperecentage` will always be initialized to `0` because `1/12 == 0`. Use `1.0f / 12` to trigger an implicit conversion instead.
   BTW, it's "percentage." Only **two** "e"s.
6. In your second loop there is a plain syntax error. You cannot define data when invoking a function and I don't even know what the rest's supposed to mean.

**Cosmetic:**

7. A good (and in C++ mandatory) habit is to **never** refer to string literals as `char*`s but as `const char*`s, except when stored in an automatic variable. Modifying string literals is undefined behavior.

After all, your code is full of mistakes. **Read a good book or tutorial about C!**
Beware: these are all the mistakes I've found **so far**. There may be more.

Comment: so it would be like this (strcmp(grade[i], "A+") == 0)

Comment: @AlessandroCalì It would be `strcmp(grade[i], "A+") == 0`.